# Need to extract data from website and push to a program

Tags: python, web-crawler

So i've been looking around trying to figure out how i could extract some specific data such as just the text, and push that data into a program that organizes the data.

So if you took homedepot.com for example and wanted to extract from each item listed under "2x4 wood" and from each item you are needing to grab the name, the description, and the specifications and import that data into a piece of software that contains this data?

So I guess that would be something like an automated data entry?

From what I've researched I'd need to write a crawler program that is designed to search a specific term and then crawl each and every page that the result returns and grab the data that I need.

However I have a bit of a problem: I don't really know any programming/scripting and am unsure where to start. I found something called Scrapy which is based off of Python. Is this what I want to use for the crawler?

The next issue I have is the fact that I have no clue on how to now import the data gathered into the software? Any tips on where I should look to find this answer?

I want to use this idea that I have to help me learn how to script.

Comment: Your question is too broad for this site. You will need to learn to program by reading documentation, books or tutorials. Feel free to post here when you have a specific question about code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should probably start by learning the language in general it would make it alot easier to do

but for the Web stuff you can use something called urllib and urllib2 these can open up the browser to get the data without actually opening the window

also there are a few automated web browsers like selenium which actually opens the window

there are many others you can look through on the internet

but that's only the web browser automation then you have to actually obtain the information and data you want for this you need something like scrapy like you said or beautifulsoup these go through the source code and pick out the information you want

since i don't exactly know what you want its kind of hard to explain but i hope this gives you somewhere to start

but like i said you should probably learn basic python and that would help alot

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Was the perfect answer.  Where would you say the best location to learn python? 

I know pythons site has a ebook but not sure that is good for noobs?

Comment: well personally books kind of bore me but they do help "Dive into python" and " learn python the hard way" ive heard are good. There are also TONS of video tutorials on youtube. if you like more hands on learning check out http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python Python is relatively easy to learn in master Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/%20%22Beautiful%20Soup). Python is a quick language to learn, focusing on readability and simplicity. There are numerous resources available online to learn python. I recommend [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). Dont be discouraged by the name, it is informative and focuses on traditional methods of language learning that are surprisingly effective.